# ruby on rails // action cable chat tutorial error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, chat, actioncable

I followed the https://www.sitepoint.com/rails-and-actioncable-adding-advanced-features tutorial, but it says:

> NameError in PersonalMessagesController#create uninitialized constant
>   PersonalMessage::NotificationBroadcastJob

```
after_create_commit do
    conversation.touch
    NotificationBroadcastJob.perform_later(self)
  end
end
```

The above error appears when I submit, but when I go back I get a message.

So I deleted code:

```
after_create_commit do
    conversation.touch
    NotificationBroadcastJob.perform_later(self)
  end
end
```

and tried to run it. I did not see the same error, but this time I can not chat live.

I followed the tutorial faithfully. I do not know why two problems arise. I need help.

my github : https://github.com/sangyeol-kim/stackoverflow_ask_ac2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try fixing file name notifications_broadcast_job.rb -> notification_broadcast_job.rb

Comment: Thank you for your advice.
i do not get notification errors with your help!
But I can not live chat.
I do not know why.
Please help me.

Comment: Yes. I did not find any error pages.
 But I can not chat in real time.
 :( ..... why is it .. I do not know T_T ..